# Where are universal variables stored in the fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

`set -xU CFLAGS "-g"` will set a universal variable that will persist across sessions. So this variable value must be store in the filesystem somewhere. Where exactly?

I would like to put this file under version control (git) in my `~/dotfiles/`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Since fish version 3.0.0 the file lives in the more portable location `~/.config/fish/fish_variables` – [Joey Sabey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593791/joey-sabey)
> (Edited to be absolute rather than relative path)

---

in `~/.config/fish/fishd.(hostname)`

Since it's host-specific, I'd recommend you put settings you want to share in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Comment: fish 2.0 replaces the hostname with the MAC address, so that you don't lose variables when you change hostnames. The recommendation to use config.fish is right on.

Comment: When made `fishd.MAC` into a symlink to track it in git, it was replaced with a file whenever I `set -U` a new variable. So that may not work for this specific purpose.

Comment: This should get you the contents of the file:

`cat ~/.config/fish/fishd.(ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}' | tr -d ':')`

Comment: Since fish version 3.0.0 the file lives in the more portable location `.config/fish/fish_variables`

Comment: Thanks @JoeySabey.